# Nested IF formula not evaluating correctly

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following formula in a cell

```
=iferror(if('Plant Master List'!$I9="Don't","Don't",
            if(search(",1S,",'Plant Master List'!$I9)>0,"SS",
            if(search(",1G,",'Plant Master List'!$I9)>0,"GG",
            if(search(",1T,",'Plant Master List'!$I9)>0,"TT",
            "Nooooo!")))))
```

If the cell in 'Plant Master List' contains `Don't` or `,1S,` the formula works, but if `,1G,` or `,1T,` are in the cell it doesn't return anything.

I'm expecting `Don't` or `SS` or `GG` or `TT`, but I am only seeing `Don't` or `SS`

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this instead:

```
=IFERROR(IF('Plant Master List'!$I9="Don't", "Don't",
         IF(REGEXMATCH('Plant Master List'!$I9, ",1S,"), "SS",
         IF(REGEXMATCH('Plant Master List'!$I9, ",1G,"), "GG",
         IF(REGEXMATCH('Plant Master List'!$I9, ",1T,") ,"TT", "Nooooo!")))))
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. Is there a problem with using search()?

Comment: using search won't return true/false as regexmatch does

Comment: Awesome - Thanx player0

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two problems in this formula

1. The outermost `ifError()` function takes two arguments. The second argument is missing.
2. The `search()` function will give a `#VALUE` error if a match is not found. But the formula construction assumes that if no match is found, the result will be zero.